# Connecting to github Spring cloud config repo not working on docker but working with intellij run

Tags: spring, docker, github

I use spring cloud config server with a connection to a private github repository to retrieve my configurations.

When I launch this micro-service with intellij, with openjdk21 it works without problem.

When I run it on docker with openjdk21-oracle it doesn't work.

I would like to point out that I put the github PAT in application.properties to test where the problem comes from.

I then tried putting my githbub repository in public and now it works on my docker container but I would like to be able to keep it private.

Has anyone already solved this problem:

```
2024-03-13T18:38:21.556Z  WARN 1 --- [config-service] [nio-8888-exec-1] .c.s.e.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository : Error occured cloning to base directory.
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566218372Z 
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566223014Z org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/bbsebb/ashs-config-repository.git: not authorized
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566226060Z  at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:249) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-6.6.1.202309021850-r.jar!/:6.6.1.202309021850-r]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566229682Z  at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:325) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-6.6.1.202309021850-r.jar!/:6.6.1.202309021850-r]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566232415Z  at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:191) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-6.6.1.202309021850-r.jar!/:6.6.1.202309021850-r]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566235113Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.cloneToBasedir(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:657) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566237968Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.copyRepository(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:632) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566240788Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.createGitClient(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:615) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566243546Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.refresh(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:295) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566246306Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:262) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566249116Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:144) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566252114Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.findOne(AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.java:62) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566256115Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.findOneFromCandidate(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:195) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566259051Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.findOne(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:178) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566271776Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.lambda$findOne$3(ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.java:75) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566274980Z  at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:565) ~[micrometer-observation-1.12.3.jar!/:1.12.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566277778Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.findOne(ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.java:75) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566280636Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.CompositeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(CompositeEnvironmentRepository.java:82) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566283463Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.ConfigServerHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(ConfigServerHealthIndicator.java:77) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566286388Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566289134Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566291783Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.getHealth(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:94) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566294518Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.getHealth(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:47) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566298403Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getLoggedHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:172) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566301422Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:145) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566304153Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:156) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566306853Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:141) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566309567Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566312219Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:81) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566314977Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:80) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566317691Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:69) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566323460Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566326300Z  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566328922Z  at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:281) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566331563Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:74) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566334480Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566337302Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$ServletWebOperationAdapter.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:327) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566340690Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:434) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566343673Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566346282Z  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566348799Z  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:259) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566351866Z  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:192) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566354967Z  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566358209Z  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:920) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566360970Z  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:830) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566363755Z  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566366549Z  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566369242Z  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566371834Z  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566374530Z  at 
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566412400Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566415086Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566417706Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566420355Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566422971Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566425780Z  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566447879Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566450682Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566453289Z  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566455897Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566458527Z  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566461107Z  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566463713Z  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566466636Z  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566469253Z  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566472086Z  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566475093Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566477756Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566480398Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566483076Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566485771Z  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566488495Z  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566493709Z Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://github.com/bbsebb/ashs-config-repository.git: not authorized
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566496538Z  at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:696) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-6.6.1.202309021850-r.jar!/:6.6.1.202309021850-r]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566499242Z  at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:465) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-6.6.1.202309021850-r.jar!/:6.6.1.202309021850-r]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566501965Z  at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:153) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-6.6.1.202309021850-r.jar!/:6.6.1.202309021850-r]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566504681Z  at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:105) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-6.6.1.202309021850-r.jar!/:6.6.1.202309021850-r]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566507358Z  at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1462) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-6.6.1.202309021850-r.jar!/:6.6.1.202309021850-r]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566510282Z  at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:238) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-6.6.1.202309021850-r.jar!/:6.6.1.202309021850-r]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566512983Z  ... 87 common frames omitted
2024-03-13T18:38:21.566515503Z 
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568720519Z 2024-03-13T18:38:21.566Z  INFO 1 --- [config-service] [nio-8888-exec-1] .c.s.e.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository : Could not refresh default label main
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568737869Z 
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568740785Z org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NoSuchRepositoryException: Cannot clone or checkout repository: https://github.com/bbsebb/ashs-config-repository.git
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568743282Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.refresh(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:319) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568745804Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:262) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568748139Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.getLocations(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:144) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568750440Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.findOne(AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.java:62) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568753158Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.findOneFromCandidate(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:195) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568755540Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.findOne(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:178) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568757931Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.lambda$findOne$3(ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.java:75) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568760358Z  at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:565) ~[micrometer-observation-1.12.3.jar!/:1.12.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568769045Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.findOne(ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.java:75) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568772336Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.CompositeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(CompositeEnvironmentRepository.java:82) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568774719Z  at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.ConfigServerHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(ConfigServerHealthIndicator.java:77) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.1.0.jar!/:4.1.0]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568777008Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568779363Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568781587Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.getHealth(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:94) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568783819Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.getHealth(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:47) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568786066Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getLoggedHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:172) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568788286Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:145) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568790561Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:156) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568792802Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:141) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568795044Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568797272Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:81) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568799472Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:80) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568802037Z  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:69) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.3.jar!/:3.2.3]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568804327Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568806550Z  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568808696Z  at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:281) ~[spring-core-6.1.4.jar!/:6.1.4]
2024-03-13T18:38:21.568812948Z  at
```